# PHP Soap client returning "WrongVersion" error. Works fine in Postman

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I am doing a SOAP request to a 3rd party service, using the standard PHP Soap Client and I am always getting a "Soap Fault: wrong version" error.

Still, I am able get the raw response (using $client->__getLastResponse()) and its returning Success.
I tried setting "soap_version" option to both "SOAP_1_1" and "SOAP_1_2" but still the same error. The "Content-Type" and the soap namespace was changed correctly in the new request, so it is applying the changes.

I also disabled wsdl cache.

I thought it could be a problem of the WSDL which is for SOAP 1.1 but I tried to use "Non WSDL" mode and it gives the same error.

If I made the same request using Postman, with exaclty the same message and headers everything works fine, which makes me think is some particularity or validation done by the PHP Soap Client.

Any more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.
The 3rd party is not responding with a valid SOAP message but in plain XML, which makes the SOAP client unable to process the message and giving that error.